# How do I take the Government Island Central Authority Jirga Para Lhao Sites Photo?

Tags: gravity-rush-2

I unlocked the Jirga Para Lhao and Hekseville Sites Photo Collection after doing the side-quest for that researcher at the start of the final Chapter. one of the photo hints points to the Government Island of the Central Authority however

> the Island was destroyed by Neu Hiraleon near to the climax and end of Chapter 2

So how do I get the photo?

Answer (score 1):

Since the Photo Collection is unlocked after you no longer have access to the Government Island of the Central Authority (infact you only have a small window outside the main quests to even access it) you'll need to go back to Kat's House and replay a mission.

you'll need to replay the mission *"No Messiah, No Message"*. after you get to the point where you find out that Syd and Cecie have been relocated you'll work with Raven to take out the guards as you sneak your way further up. when you reach the main front gate there there is 3 ways you can go

1. go outside where there is one guard walking and 2 guards up ahead on the outside of the wall
2. down an ally where there is 3 guards gathered
3. an path opposite the gate that takes you up

take 3 and before you catch up to Syd and Cecie (who are in the courtyard infront of the main building) you'll start to see the fish statue mentioned in the hint. you'll be able to take the camera out and photograph it to save it to your collection.

i'm not 100% sure if the photo is saved if you Retire the mission but i'd complete the mission just in case